# How to customize keybindings on ST i.e. simple/suckless terminal?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Here is the corresponding part of my `config.h`:

```
/* Internal keyboard shortcuts. */
#define MODKEY Mod1Mask
#define TERMMOD (ControlMask|ShiftMask)

static Shortcut shortcuts[] = {
    /* mask                 keysym          function        argument */
    { XK_ANY_MOD,           XK_Break,       sendbreak,      {.i =  0} },
    { ControlMask,          XK_Print,       toggleprinter,  {.i =  0} },
    { ShiftMask,            XK_Print,       printscreen,    {.i =  0} },
    { XK_ANY_MOD,           XK_Print,       printsel,       {.i =  0} },
    { TERMMOD,              XK_Prior,       zoom,           {.f = +1} },
    { TERMMOD,              XK_Next,        zoom,           {.f = -1} },
    { TERMMOD,              XK_Home,        zoomreset,      {.f =  0} },
    { TERMMOD,              XK_C,           clipcopy,       {.i =  0} },
    { TERMMOD,              XK_V,           clippaste,      {.i =  0} },
    { TERMMOD,              XK_Y,           selpaste,       {.i =  0} },
    { TERMMOD,              XK_Num_Lock,    numlock,        {.i =  0} },
};
```

Now, what is the purpose of the column `argument`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The address of the argument in the fourth column is passed to the function listed in the third column. For example, note how the `zoom()` function is listed twice under different arguments for different shortcuts.

---

The `Shortcut` data type that makes up the `shortcuts[]` array in your question is defined in `x.c` as a struct of four members:

```
typedef struct {
    uint mod;
    KeySym keysym;
    void (*func)(const Arg *);
    const Arg arg;
} Shortcut;
```

The last member of `Shortcut`, `Arg`, is defined in `st.h` as a union of four:

```
typedef union {
    int i;
    uint ui;
    float f;
    const void *v;
} Arg;
```

An example of `func` from a `Shortcut` getting called with the address of the union member from the struct happens in `keypress()` from `x.c`, where `bp` points to a `Shortcut`:

```
if (ksym == bp->keysym && match(bp->mod, e->state)) {
    bp->func(&(bp->arg));
    ...
```

A concrete example of leveraging this setup can be seen in `zoom()` where the float in the `Arg` union is used. From the configuration in your question, `arg->f` in this function can be `+1` or `-1` to grow or shrink the font size:

```
void
zoom(const Arg *arg)
{
    Arg larg;

    larg.f = usedfontsize + arg->f;
    zoomabs(&larg);
}
```

Comment: Yes, after asking the question I went to look into the source code and it's pretty simple. Thanks.